# angularjs ng-grid keep selection on update

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I'm trying to use the `ng-grid` setup and I have the following problem.

The data I am displaying changes very frequently, every 5 seconds or so. But not a lot of new data gets added to the list.

When i set data to the ng-grid the user can start looking at the data. but when I update the data after about 5 seconds the selections the user has made and the grouping is lost.

http://plnkr.co/edit/eK1aeRI67qMROqDUtPnb

Is there anyway to keep the selection and/or the grouping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to go through and merge the data in a for loop. If you replace the entire array, you're replacing the object references, and therefor you will lose any changes you've made.

The other option would be to keep your selections in a different array or dictionary, then remap your properties after you replace your array. Notice here you're going to need to use a reference type so changes persist to your selections array.

So like [psuedo-code]:

```
// a dictionary of reference types (IMPORTANT that they are objects!)
// to hold selection data.
var selections = {
  'Name1' : { value: 'selection' },
  'Name2': { value: 'selection2' }
}

$scope.getMyData = function () {    
    // do whatever to get your data here.
    $scope.myData = [
       { name: 'Name1' },
       { name: 'Name2' }
    ];

    // update your objects in your array. 
    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.myData.length; i++) {
       var data = $scope.myData[i];
       var selection = selections[data.name];
       if(selection) {
           data.selection = selection;
       }
    }    
};

// initial load
$scope.getMyData();

// your test interval
setInterval(function () {
    $scope.$apply(function (){
       $scope.getMyData();
    });
}, 5000);
```

Comment: not needed anymore (s. answer by timothyswt). Just add the primaryKey Property to gridOptions and specify the column that has unique values.

Answer (score 2):

We are going to be adding a primaryKey option in the next version that will allow the grid to key off that instead of references.

Comment: Thanks this is really great. Any change you would know which next version the primary key is being added?

Comment: Ah sorry I could have searched a bit better and found the issue https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/233 - so its coming in 2.1 release